Freezing cookie pies
I made some home-made cookie pies with chocolate bars. I will need to know whether I can freeze them and how long I can

Welcome to the Cooking Stack Exchange. We would need to know the recipe to make any judgement on whether they can be frozen and defrosted successfully.
